# Top Questions of the Week #17

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 17 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question seems like a good one to me because it's something that I believe a lot of people don't understand the consequences or dangers of with regards to the power of nature:

- [Is it bad to leave your computer on during a thunderstorm?](https://superuser.com/questions/287709/is-it-bad-to-leave-your-computer-on-during-a-thunderstorm/287711)

The question was clear and easy to understand, and is a problem that many of us do face from time-to-time.

The reference to nature is interesting too because so much of what we do with computers has so little to do with the world outside, and this topic helps to remind us that there is more to life than just sitting in front of computers all day.

(I hope I'm posting this in the right place -- I didn't see anything in the blog that looked like it was related to your request to post favourite questions; so far this week, that is one of my favourite questions.)

Answer (score 6):

[What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)

Explains Environment Variables for different Operating Systems in a quick, dense, info-packed package. (You don't have to go through an entire 10-page article learning how they work; just learn the relevant stuff here.)

Answer (score 2):

I never really thought about [storing harddrives near electric lines](https://superuser.com/questions/288109/storing-hard-drive-near-electric-wire), but I probably have stored a harddrive near an AC line from time to time.

I am very aware that harddrives are powered by electricity (DC), although I never thought of the long-term effects of storing a harddrive near an AC power cord.

This seems like a topic that people should be aware of so users know how to treat their equipment.